# How could I describe a function whose domain is x>=1 for integers, starts at 3 f(1)=3, then multiplied by 2 f(2)=6, then by 3 f(3)=18, repeat

Tags: functions, recursive-algorithms, combinations, multinomial-coefficients

$$f(1)=3 \quad f(2)=6\quad f(3)=18\quad  f(4)=36 \quad f(5)=108$$

How can I define this function? The function is recursive and multiplies by 2 then 3 alternatively. I know I could solve this in code, but I'm not sure of the mathematical terms one could use to make a function like this.
Let me know if I'm not clear and thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you please fix the title? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $f(n)=3^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\cdot 2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$? Here $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the smallest integer not less than $x$, and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer not greater than $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by smallest and largest integer. This function works for the even numbers, but I'm not sure what that notation is.

Comment: @PhilipRego The notation is for the floor and ceiling functions.  You can think of it as rounding up (for ceiling) and (down) for floor to the nearest integer.  For example, the floor of 2.5 (the largest integer not greater than 2.5) is 2.  The floor of 7 is 7.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: This only needs to work for integers. And it doesn't work for the odd numbers f(1) doesn't equal 3

Comment: It works for integers, and f(1)=3, since $\lceil 1/2\rceil$=1 and $\lfloor 1/2\rfloor$=0. You can prove the rule is correct by induction.

Answer (score 1):

For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we can express

$$  
  \begin{array}{l l}
    f(2k-1)&= 3^k 2^{k-1} \\
    f(2k) &= 3^k 2^k 
  \end{array} .$$